# SpatialPolygonsDataFrame not plotting with R

Tags: r, geospatial

I am loading a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame from (downloaded from [here](http://gadm.org/country)).

When I try plot this using:

```
library(sp)
library(tmap)
brazil<-readRDS("BRA_adm1.rds")
qtm(brazil)
```

R is engaged for a few minutes but then there is no output at the end.
Not sure where I am going wrong.

When I try `data(Europe);qtm(Europe)` it produces an output.

Any help apreciated.

Comment: You code works for me .. the only difference wtih `data(Europe);qtm(Europe)` is that I have to wait a little more the brazil ...

Comment: Oh thanks, I was being impatient. I ran `png("test.png");qtm(brazil);dev.off()` and it was a lot faster and prodeced the image. I guess the xterm display is slower.